# Finite Element Solution to Poisson Equation with Boundary Condition at Infinity

Tags: finite-element-method, poissons-equation

I am solving the simple poisson equation
$$-\nabla \cdot (\epsilon\nabla u) = \rho$$
using a finite element mesh (rho is just a point charge).  I would like to implement a boundary condition such that
$$\lim_{r \to \infty}   u(r) = 0$$
Is it possible to implement this boundary condition?  I.e. Can I place a boundary condition on the boundary of the mesh that will simulate the above limit?

Thanks

Comment: You could use a mesh which is "large enough" to simulate $r \rightarrow \infty$ and set $u = 0$ on its border... or did I miss something in your question ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Yes, this is what I am currently doing at the moment. I was just wondering if there was a "cheaper" solution computationally, as I have to quadruple my mesh size to get good results, and I am only interested in a small region around the source charge.

Comment: What basis functions are you using?

Comment: Linear Lagrange basis functions.